# How to make keyboard with React Native

Tags: keyboard, react-native

I want to make a keyboard like [SwiftKey Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) and [Gboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin) which is also used on Android. It is possible to do such an application with react-native. How to follow a path.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but I've seen this library used a couple times for making keyboards in react-native: [react-native-custom-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-custom-keyboard)